# Is there a way to export Group Details?

Tags: groups, export

Is there a way to export Group Details? I've tried to look into the custom reports, and various report options, without success. Ultimately, it would be great if you could export group details similar to "actions" on other windows (i.e., Contact Search).

Comment: Welcome to SE! Can you be more specific about what you mean by Group Details? Do you mean who is a member or what?

Comment: Hello, Thank you! From the Manage Groups Window, I can see a listing of my Groups, # (count), type, etc. I am wondering if there Export this detail?

Comment: if you are using Drupal it looks like you can build a View based on Groups

Comment: Thank you, we are using Joomla.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with SearchKit, but you'll need to be on the latest CiviCRM (5.42+) to export.

[Here is a URL](https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/search#/create/Group?params=%7B%22version%22:4,%22select%22:%5B%22title%22,%22COUNT(Group_GroupContact_Contact_01.id)%20AS%20COUNT_Group_GroupContact_Contact_01_id%22,%22group_type:label%22%5D,%22orderBy%22:%7B%7D,%22where%22:%5B%5D,%22groupBy%22:%5B%22id%22%5D,%22join%22:%5B%5B%22Contact%20AS%20Group_GroupContact_Contact_01%22,%22LEFT%22,%22GroupContact%22,%5B%22id%22,%22%3D%22,%22Group_GroupContact_Contact_01.group_id%22%5D,%5B%22Group_GroupContact_Contact_01.status:name%22,%22%3D%22,%22%5C%22Added%5C%22%22%5D%5D%5D,%22having%22:%5B%5D%7D) that contains the search on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org, you should be able to modify the URL for your own site.  You can add more fields as needed.

You can also just replicate the search from this screenshot:
Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an export for this is CiviCRM, but you could select all the table entries on the screen and then paste it into Excel (or something similar), which would give you the information on this screen. Works if you have up to 100 groups and you set to 110 entries per page (or do it in multiple pages. And also expand any groups that are nested before exporting.

Comment: Thank you, we're doing a similar process currently. Appreciate the feedback!